# Implicit return value from a proc

Tags: nim-lang

The nim lang [tutorial](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html#procedures-result-variable) here says -

> A procedure that does not have any return statement and does not use the special result variable returns the value of its last expression.

Why does my `echo res` print 0 ? Shouldn't I expect the last statement `a mod b` (= 3) to be returned?

```
proc divmod(a, b: int; res, remainder: var int): int =
  res = a div b        
  remainder = a mod b  
  

var
  x, y: int

let res: int = divmod(8, 5, x, y) # modifies x and y

echo res
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `divmod` proc `remainder = a mod b` is a statement, not an expression, so divmod returns the default value for int which is 0.

I'm not sure why'd you want to both return remainder by a mutable argument and the result, but this is how you can do it:

```
proc divmod(a, b: int; res, remainder: var int): int =
  res = a div b        
  remainder = a mod b
  remainder # or result = remainder
  

var
  x, y: int

let res: int = divmod(8, 5, x, y) # modifies x and y

echo res
```

This is how your proc can be remade if you don't really need to modify existing values:

```
proc divmod(a, b: int): (int, int) =
  (a div b, a mod b)

let (x, y) = divmod(8, 5)

echo x, " ", y
```